# Does xtify support native apps made by Adobe Flash Professional?

Tags: android, iphone, flash, push, xtify

Does anybody know if xtify is supported when developing iPhone and Android apps with Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5? If not, what are the best push messaging platforms/services available to use with such Flash-generated apps?

Thanks,
Matt

PS. I don't have the rep to create a tag for xtify, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xtify uses XMPP on Android and on more recent versions Cloud to Device, on iOS it's largely dependent on APNS just as Urban Airship is...

AFAIK Adobe Flash for iOS uses [Low Level Virtual Machine (LLVM) compiler infrastructure](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html) therefore you may not have the ability to include 3rd party SDKs.

I would reach out to Xtify's tech support, they will go out of the way to try to solve your problem / support your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is 'no'. Have a look on the Urban Airship support [message](http://help.urbanairship.com/discussions/questions/473-using-urban-airship-to-enable-push-notifications-in-iphone-app-developed-in-flash)

Comment: Ok, that seems fair enough for Urban Airship, because they use Apple's proprietary services. However, I believe Xtify uses a variation on XMPP, meaning that it should be technically possible on any platform supporting XMPP right?